# Check if 2 values are in a nested list and print the values of the list

Tags: python

I ask for an Identification number, example(6373383-D) and a pin.
I have a nested list like this:

```
cliente = [[0, "Carlos", "Perez Rodriguez", "123342344-D", 4, "ES6621000418401234567891", 1234, 3000, "No"], 
[1, "Ana", "Martin Perez", "19786444-E", 7, "ES6000491500051234567892", 6789, 8000, "No"], 
[2, "Maria", "Sanchez Agudo", "67893456-A", 2, "ES9420805801101234567891", 1111, 10000, "No"], 
[3, "Paco", "Sainz Sanchez", "56782341-B", 2, "ES9000246912501234567891", 9876, 2345, "No"],
[4, "Marcos", "Calvo Rodriguez", "56783452-D", 9, "ES7100302053091234567895", 3456, 8000, "No"]]
```

If he puts for example 123342344-D and 1234 in PIN i have to show the values of that list.

The code I have is:

```
    #coding=utf-8
cliente=[["Carlos", "Perez Rodriguez", "123342344-D", 4, "ES6621000418401234567891", 1234, 3000, "No"], ["Ana", "Martin Perez", "19786444-E", 7, "ES6000491500051234567892", 6789, 8000, "No"], ["Maria", "Sanchez Agudo", "67893456-A", 2, "ES9420805801101234567891", 1111, 10000, "No"], ["Paco", "Sainz Sanchez", "56782341-B", 2, "ES9000246912501234567891", 9876, 2345, "No"], ["Marcos", "Calvo Rodriguez", "56783452-D", 9, "ES7100302053091234567895", 3456, 8000, "No"] ]
def clientes(): 
    respuesta=True
    while respuesta:
        print ("Ha elegido la opcion clientes, por favor, identifiquese usando DNI y PIN: ")
        dni = input("DNI: ")
        pin = int(input("PIN: "))
        if dni in (dni[2] for dni in cliente):
            if pin in (pin[5] for pin in cliente):
                for r in cliente:
                    if dni == cliente[r][3] and pin == cliente[r][6]:
                        print("*-----------------------------------------------------------------*\n")
                        print("\nNombre: "+ cliente[r][0])
                        print("\nApellidos: "+ cliente[r][1])
                        print("\nDNI: "+ cliente[r][2])
                        print("\nAntiguedad: "+ cliente[r][3])
                        print("\nCuenta IBAN: "+ cliente[r][4])
                        print("\nPIN: "+ cliente[r][5])
                        print("\nBalance: "+ cliente[r][6])
                        print("\nTiene oferta: "+ cliente[r][7])
                        print("\n*-----------------------------------------------------------------*")
        else:
            print("El cliente no está en la lista")
```

I want something similar, we never used dynamic and I´m not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that the fourth item of any sublist of `cliente` would contain identification number and seventh item of the sublists contain the pin, you can print the sublists which contain those items like this :

```
print([k for k in cliente if (k[3]=='123342344-D' and k[6] == 1234)])
```

or if the sublists are not ordered then try :

```
print([k for k in cliente if ('123342344-D' in k and 1234 in k)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write dynamic filter function:

```
filter_func = lambda id,pin: lambda row: (row[3]==id) and (row[6]==pin )
list(filter(filter_func("123342344-D", 1234), cliente))
```

Results:

```
[[0, 'Carlos', 'Perez Rodriguez', '123342344-D', 4, 'ES6621000418401234567891', 1234, 3000, 'No']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
res = [i for i in cliente if i[3]=='123342344-D' and i[6] == 1234]
print(repr(res[0]) if len(res) else 'Not found')
```